# Why doesn't area.tag_refresh() refresh the area?

Tags: python, scripting

I have an `IMAGE_EDITOR` area opened. I change the loaded image's content from another area, but `area.tag_refresh()` doesn't update it automatically, only when I do something related to the `IMAGE_EDITOR` area (zooming, moving the image in it, making the area bigger or anything like that).
Fortunately I can touch the area from code to make the image refresh itself without touching it manually, but it's hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

```
def img_redraw_handler(scene):
    ...
    img_bpy.pixels.foreach_set(img_np.ravel())
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
            #area.tag_refresh() # <-- This one doesn't work
            # HACK TO REDRAW - START
            area.type = 'OUTLINER'
            area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
            # HACK TO REDRAW- END
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre.append(img_redraw_handler)
```

SOLUTION:

```
def img_redraw_handler(scene):
    ...
    img_bpy.pixels.foreach_set(img_np.ravel())
    img_bpy.update()
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre.append(img_redraw_handler)
```

many thanks to **[Sietse Brouwer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/154603/sietse-brouwer)**

Comment: Haven't tested it, but you can try an `img_bpy.update()` before the `area.tag_refresh()`.

Comment: Yeess!
img_bpy.update() is all that's required, not even area.tag_refresh() is necessary.
Thank you very much! I would like to give you an upvote so much, sadly I cannot:(

Comment: Glad I could help. I've added an answer, for others who come across this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is already in the question, but for future reference I will post it as an 'official' answer.

After setting pixels of an image, an `img_bpy.update()` is required to reflect the changes in Blender.

```
def img_redraw_handler(scene):
    ...
    img_bpy.pixels.foreach_set(img_np.ravel())
    img_bpy.update()

bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_pre.append(img_redraw_handler)
```